# How do I enter subquestions into table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, links

I am using a table of contents defined by me so that we have links to questions in the table of contents. Now, how do I modify this code so that we also have subquestions with links in the table of contents?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}
\newtheorem{ques}{Question}

\makeatletter
\def\ll@ques{%
    {\bfseries \thmt@thmname~ \protect\numberline{\theques.~}}}
\def\l@thmt@theorem{} 
\makeatother
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \title{Title}
    \maketitle
    \listoftheorems[ignoreall, show={ques},title = {Contents}]
    \begin{ques}
        This is a ques.
    \end{ques}
\end{document}
```

I've tried using `enumerate` environment after my question, but that doesn't create the links in the table of contents (obviously). I've also tried defining another environment named `subques`, but then I don't know how to alter this code of table of contents to include links to another counter. Also, in this case I don't know how to number my `subques` like `(ques no.)(i)`, `(ques no.)(ii)`, etc. The `\numberwithin` command makes it `(ques no.).1`, `(ques no.).2`, etc.

Please help.

Comment: Will your document only contain questions, subquestions and their solution or will you also have more "traditional"  sectioning commands such as `\section`, `\subsection`... inside of your document? If not, you could probably make `\section` behave like question and `\subsection` like a subquestion?

Comment: @leandriis, No, I don't have sections and subsections.

Answer (score 1):

I have never come across the `thmtools` package before and I'm not inclined to delve into it. One way to get subquestions is to basically repeat your `ques` code.

```
% subqinlistprob.tex  SE 568134

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}
\newtheorem{ques}{Question}

\newtheorem{subques}{Subquestion}

\makeatletter
\def\ll@ques{%
    {\bfseries \thmt@thmname~ \protect\numberline{\theques.~}}}
\def\l@thmt@theorem{} 
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\def\ll@subques{%
    {\bfseries \thmt@thmname~ \protect\numberline{\thesubques.~}}}
\def\l@thmt@theorem{} 
\makeatother
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \title{Title}
    \maketitle
    \listoftheorems[ignoreall, show={ques,subques},title = {Contents}]
    \begin{ques}
        This is a ques.
      \begin{subques}
        This is a subquestion.
      \end{subques}
      \begin{subques}
        This is another subquestion.
      \end{subques}
    \end{ques}
  \begin{ques}
    This is another ques.
      \begin{subques}
        This is a subquestion.
      \end{subques}
  \end{ques}
\end{document}
```

This provides one answer as to how to get your subquestions in the ToC. I realise that it does not answer your question about subquestion numbering and appearance but that then makes 3 questions and we prefer one question at a time. Perhaps `thmtools` can help with the other ones.